# Не могу расшифровать зашифрованные файлы

Tags: python

есть скрип, который шифрует файлы в определенном каталоге, шифруются файлы вроде как нормально. Но почему-то не могу потом эти файлы расшифровать, при работе скрипта в консоли вылетает такая ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт я писал года полтора назад и по гайду. Подскажите пожалуйста как теперь расшифровать данные? 
Сам скрипт дешифровки прилагаю:

```
def Decript(filename):
file_content = "";
with open(filename, 'rb') as fobj:
    private_key = RSA.import_key(
        open(appdata_filepath_prk).read(), #prk.bin это приватный ключ
        passphrase=code
    ) # Открываем зашифрованный файл
    enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [
        fobj.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1)
    ]
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    print(enc_session_key)
    session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)
    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    file_content = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
    print(file_content)
with open(filename, 'wb') as fobj:
    fobj.write(file_content)
```

`appdata_filepath_prk` - это путь к файлу с приватным ключом, который генерируется скриптом шифровки.
Ошибка указывается на строку 44, это вот этот кусок

```
session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)
```

UPD: решил переписать скрипт используя библиотеку **pyAesCrypt**, но она, как оказалось, довольно медленно шифрует файлы, по сравнению с предыдущим вариантом

Comment: На самом деле не очень понятно, почему выбрасывается исключение. У вас есть доступ к этому методу, либо документация, если это библиотека? Судя по типу `ValueError`, возможно просто передается не тот тип аргумента

Comment: А вы уверены что у вас правильный ключ?(prk.bin да?)

Comment: @Victor, да, ключ точно правильный, выводил его через Print

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus, тип правильный вроде как

Comment: а у вас строчка `print(enc_session_key)` все верно выводит?